# Preventing uwsgi_response_write_body_do() TIMEOUT

Tags: uwsgi

We use uwsgi with the python3 plugin, under nginx, to serve potentially hundreds of megabytes of data per query.  Sometimes when nginx is queried from client a slow network connection, a uwsgi worker dies with "uwsgi_response_write_body_do() TIMEOUT !!!".

I understand the uwsgi python plugin reads from the iterator our app returns as fast as it can, trying to send the data over the uwsgi protocol unix socket to nginx.  The HTTPS/TCP connection to the client from nginx will get backed up from a slow network connection and nginx will pause reading from its uwsgi socket.  uwsgi will then fail some writes towards nginx, log that message and die.

Normally we run nginx with uwsgi buffering disabled.  I tried enabling buffering, but it doesn't help as the amount of data it might need to buffer is 100s of MBs.

Our data is not simply read out of a file, so we can't use file offload.

Is there a way to configure uwsgi to pause reading from the our python iterator if that unix socket backs up?

The existing question here "uwsgi_response_write_body_do() TIMEOUT - But uwsgi_read_timeout not helping" doesn't help, as we have buffering off.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, adding `socket-timeout = 60` is helping for all but the slowest client connection speeds.
That's sufficient so this question can be closed.